# Elastic Beanstalk Django Database Configuration

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm running into a situation where my django application cannot connect to the postgres instance that have both been spun up by the same EBS environment.

1. I've confirmed that the security groups that both the RDS and EC2 instances in are setup to communicate.
2. I confirmed the credentials for the database are correct as i am able to use the CLI for postgres to log in both locally, as well as while ssh'd into the EC2 instance.
3. Third, and weirdest of the symptoms, is that the migrations work. So while migrating, the application is able to connect to the database and run migrations, but when trying to access those tables via the `views.py` files, i get the dreaded `password authentication failed` error.

I'm totally stuck, and have been trying everything i can think of for the last few hours. Any help i can get would be a huge huge help. Thanks!

Comment: are you giving defaults like `DB_PASSWORD=os.environ.get(DB_PASS,"somedefault")` and maybe env not getting loaded I faced same issue once and bug was not loading env properly. do `print(DB_PASSWORD)` and check

Comment: so, it looks like it works if i switch Postgres versions? It doesnt really explain why the migrations work and the read only side doesnt, but it seems to be working now

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so unfortunately I don't necessarily know why this is the case, but it seemed to fix the issue if i switched the RDS Postgres instance from version 11.1 to version 10.x. Hopefully this saves someone else some time! Sorry i can't point to why that fixed it

Comment: could be another reason I guess but good it solved your issue